# Activity onNewIntent Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, onnewintent

I initialize my lists in my activity onCreate() like below:

```
private List<MyItem> filtered;
@Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
      filtered = new ArrayList<>();

      // more things
}
```

And when i try to use filtered items from onNewIntent sometimes i get a null pointer exception.

```
 @Override
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
      super.onNewIntent(intent);
      filtered.clear();
   }
```

How could it be possible?

Edit: My Activity's launchmode is **SingleTask**

Edit 2:

I cannot send more useful logs because this crash is in production. Only i get some fabric logs.

Thanks for your help but i cannot paste whole code cause of privacy.

I think i have a problem on SingleTask-OnCreate-OnNewIntent usage. Simply i'm trying to open my app from notification with a parameter decides which fragment will be opened when user navigates to activity.

Do you have any examples about this which contains SingleTask-OnCreate-OnNewIntent implementations?

Thanks to all for help.

Comment: Post your logcat if you encounter a `NullPointerException`! Like that I'll just guess `filtered` is null in `onNewIntent()`...

Comment: @savepopulation Has the accepted answer helped you in any way? I am having a similar issue, and am not able to reproduce the issue. Can only see fabric logs of the crashes :(

Comment: sorry i left the project i'm having this issue so i cannot see whats happening with build tools 25.0.2 in production. I made a few researches about this issue and according to what i found, decided to accept @Mr-IDE's answer.

Comment: i think this happens when you define a launch mode -except standart- to your activity and when it's finishing you try to start it again. So it's reasonable to check if it's finishing. i hope this'll help you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That was useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The team at Open Whisper Systems encountered the same problem:

https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/issues/2971

They think it's caused by a bug in the Android framework, when it calls `onNewIntent()` very shortly after `onCreate()`, even if you call `finish()` from within your `onCreate()`. This eventually causes `null` objects to be used in `onNewIntent()` and then a `NullPointerException`, because the objects haven't been set up in the usual `onCreate()`. It seems to be a rare scenario or a race condition between `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()`.

They seem to have fixed it by checking for `isFinishing()` in `onNewIntent()`, to prevent `onNewIntent()` from continuing:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onNewIntent()");
 
    if (isFinishing()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Activity is finishing...");
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Source 1: https://github.com/SilenceIM/Silence/commit/c0acae1124c0c066fd961d21d3ec9b989574125d

Source 2: https://github.com/SilenceIM/Silence/blob/0b4ea2412273f4e4918cff8f304380d3151ff6d4/src/org/smssecure/smssecure/ConversationActivity.java#L225-L249

---

**Update:** 10 November 2017: This problem seems to happen much less often when **upgrading the build tools** in `app/build.gradle`:

```
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
```

It seemed to happen more often with older build tools, like `buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'`, but the fix is still needed, as it still happens on rare occasions.

Comment: About your 10 nov. 2017 update, why are you assuming this ? I think it may be related to the appcompat version more than the build tools version , not ?

Comment: @crgarridos, Through app monitoring and analytics, it can be seen that updating the build tools version reduces the number of times this bug happens by a large amount. But it doesn't 100% fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the lifecycle in mind, maybe you are returning to your Activity from some point where onCreate() is not called (for example if you have set launchMode=singleTask or something in your manifest). Maybe initialize/repopulate your ArrayList in onResume() and also check if it is not null, on Resume() is called for sure when you return to your Activity.

Comment: my activity's launchmode is single task. in which kind of situations it can be possible new intent gets called without onCreate? can you give an example? thanks.

Comment: f.e. if you have switch to another Activity and return to your singleTask Activity, onNewIntent() is called and onCreate() is not called

Comment: thats correct but onCreate will be called if single task activity is destroyed. if it's not destroyed my lists will not be null. is it not right?

Comment: Well, your ArrayList maybe shouldn't be null, but it obviously is, so you have to either provide more code or better do some debugging yourself to find on which point the ArrayList becomes null. What do you mean with 'onCreate will be called if single task activity is destroyed' ?

Comment: i cannot catch how this error occurs. That's the problem. And i get logs from fabric. I get this error in production.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `NullPointerException` in `onNewIntent()` method then probably `filtered` object is null.

Try this way

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

   //Check for null value and then proceed. 
   if(filtered != null)
      filtered.clear();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but my code is more complicated than this. so if check is not suitable.

Comment: @savepopulation please post your code. So we can help you out there.

Comment: i cannot post cause of privacy. i'm sorry. :(